# Install a new tub that has cracks?

Tags: bathtub

first question here. We're having a bathroom remodeled. The first tub that was delivered had a huge crack in it, so we asked for a replacement. The second one took 2 weeks to arrive. It has two tiny cracks in the corner. One appears to be (shoddily) covered over by plaster.

We're ready to send this back and ask for another replacement, knowing fully well that this will delay our project further. Is there any universe in which we'd actually install this instead? What would the risks of doing so be?

[image]

Comment: Given that someone clearly thought it was ok to do that bodge job of a repair and then ship it out, I wouldn't just be sending it back, I'd be blacklisting that supplier.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what country is this? It boggles my mind that someone would even consider sending out a cracked bathtub and the "repair" just takes the cake. Are they making a stupid joke or something?

Comment: I think you should order from somewhere else.

Comment: Welcome, Seeru.

Don't even think about it. You bought a new tub and you should get one which meets the factory specification in every respect - which won't include cracks.

My own closest experience was being offered three sub-standard Welsh dressers before getting a good one. How is that different, except my dresser didn't hold up a project?

Legal details might differ in your jurisdiction but here in the UK, I'd be asking the suppliers why they wouldn't be liable for costs and punitive damages if they continued to delay my project.

Comment: Thanks, all. This is in San Francisco. The showroom that we're working with was rather pissed off too about this. It's "being handled". They rushed us a new tub, which looks great. Now waiting for the plumber to give us time of day :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The key questions are:

1. Is it warranted? For how long? Are you willing to accept liability for failure after that period (or after the company closes its doors)?
2. Does the warranty cover replacement expenses? I'd wager no. The problem there is apparent.

Don't do it unless you have no practical alternative or are compensated for potential costs in advance.

Comment: And because these are troubling times, do you expect the company to be around in a few years to claim the warranty?

Comment: I definitely agree with this. Do not install it. If you do, it will bug you until you move out.+

Answer (score 13):

I would send it back and for sure not get that type of tub again.   If tubs are cracking during the shipping process I would not trust them to stay in one piece when there is a bunch of weight and water in them.

I mean I wouldn't even think about it.   I have had cracked tubs come to me for new bathrooms and I have never thought about getting a new one.   I mean you take your cast iron tubs that you get in a lot of older home, and you are not cracking those without a hammer.   There is no way you do all of that plumbing and tile work and waterproofing and all that and skimp on a tub that will have problems and snowball into a much larger project when it cracks.

Comment: Could just be that some knucklehead dropped them off a forklift.

Comment: @isherwood - I don't disagree with the sentiment and for sure that could be the cause (twice maybe....).   But one thing I have learned is that whether defective or open box or whatever...  it simply isn't worth the risk if what you are buying is time intensive.   Yea I will get some discounted fixtures that take 2 screws to install, but a tub... no way.

Comment: @isherwood - That's as maybe, but then someone else thought it would be ok to monkey patch them with filler and hope that (somehow) nobody noticed instead of supplying a new one.  I would return it and then buy a different tub *from a different supplier*.

Answer (score 2):

Get an enameled steel one instead.

One in picture looks like acrylic tub, and these appear to be quite fragile (and expensive). Good old enameled steel is more durable and easier to replace - it doesn't even need fancy supports.
If you are after "not so cold to the touch" feeling of acrylic tub, you can put the steel one into a dedicated styrofoam stand, so it keeps the water warm longer. It is not warm like acrylic, but bearable.

Experience: First acrylic tub came broken, second had ugly scratches, that manufacturer removed making *another* set of scratches. At this point seller gave up and returned money. Bought plain regular enameled steel for fraction of the price.

[Mind that depending on local code, steel tub might require grounding wire.]

Comment: I have had plenty of Acrylic tubs with no issues during delivery or installation, they have their drawbacks and benefits but cracking on delivery is not one of them.